# how can i store the printing result, obtained by "for statement" variable?

Tags: python

I am counting some specific bigram words frequency. 
and below are the part of my codes.

```
sorted_bigrams = sorted(bigrams.items(), key = lambda pair:pair[1], reverse = True)

for bigram, count in sorted_bigrams:
    if bigram == ("interesting", "news"):
        print count
```

here, I want to store the counting number of the printing result "count", which is the counting number of bigram "interesting, news"

how can I do it..

Comment: Assign it to a variable maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the total count:

```
sorted_bigrams = sorted(bigrams.items(), key = lambda pair:pair[1], reverse = True)

total_count = 0
for bigram, count in sorted_bigrams:
    if bigram == ("interesting", "news"):
        print count
        total_count += count
print total_count
```

If you want to keep track of the breakdown of the counts:

```
sorted_bigrams = sorted(bigrams.items(), key = lambda pair:pair[1], reverse = True)

counts = []
for bigram, count in sorted_bigrams:
    if bigram == ("interesting", "news"):
        print count
        counts.append(count)
print counts
```

Comment: Glad I could help; If my answer was helpful, you can upvote it, and accept it. If you don't know how, you may want to take a look here: [how to accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) and there too: [why accepting answers is important](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)

Answer (score 0):

if `bigrams` is a dict storing bigram as key and count as value, then you don't need to sort it in order to get total count as the keys are unique.

if `bigrams` is list of tuples, you can use `collections.Counter` to get the total count.

```
In [30]: bigrams
Out[30]: [(('a', 'b'), 10), (('d', 'f'), 3), (('a', 'c'), 15), (('a', 'b'), 2)]

In [31]: counter = Counter()

In [32]: for key, val in bigrams:
    counter[key] += val
   ....:     

In [33]: counter[('a', 'b')]
Out[33]: 12
```